# Double integral over a square region

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

Suppose we have a function $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{xy}$ defined over the square $1\leq x\leq 2, 1\leq y\leq 2$ and we want to find the volume under the function over the square.

My attempt:

The volume, given by $V$ is equal to $V=\int_{1}^2\int_{1}^2\frac{1}{xy}dxdy$
$=\int_{1}^2\frac{1}{y}[\ln{x}]_{1}^2dy=\ln{2}\ln{2}=[\ln{2}]^2$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct

Comment: notice that the two integrals are separable and identical so you can find one and square it :)

Comment: Great, thank you!